# Page wont Navigate after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, navigation, mern

so im trying to navigate after the user is logged in. I have tried redirect. history.push and Navigate. iv also tried to return after the localstorage call and still nothing.
currently the line used to navigate to a new page is

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const {data} = await axios.post('/api/signin', {
                email,
                password
            });

            console.log(data);

            if  (data.success === true){
                setValues({ email: '', password:''});
                toast.success("Log In successfully");
                localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data))
                if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        Navigate('/user/Userdashboard');
                    }, 2000);
                }
              
            }
```

also if you know how to refresh page on login that would be awesome

Comment: Does it go inside to the second if block? `if (typeof window !== "undefined"){`

Comment: what is `Navigate` and are you certain it's being called (just check with a console.log)?

Comment: Close, thanks for the help, I shared the answer that i modified. cheer

Answer (score 0):

```
  try{
        const res = await fetch('/api/signin', {
          method:'POST',
          body:JSON.stringify({ email,password}),
          headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        });

        const data = await res.json()
        console.log(data); 
        if(data){
          location.assign('/user/Userdashboard');
        }

      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
try{
    const res = await fetch('/api/signin', {
      method:'POST',
      body:JSON.stringify({ email,password}),
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    });

    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data); 
    if(data){
        setValues({ email: '', password:''});
        toast.success("Log In successfully");
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data))
       window.location.assign('/UserDashboard');
    }

  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```